# How do I take the derivative of this vector valued function?

Tags: calculus, vectors

**Problem:** Find the velocity at time $t$ of the particle whose position is $\hat{r}(t)$:
\begin{align*} \hat{r} = e^{-t} \cos(e^t) \hat{i} + e^{-t} \sin(e^t) \hat{j} - e^t \hat{k} \end{align*}

**This is what I did:**
\begin{align*}
\frac{d \hat{r}}{dt} &= \big( -e^{-t} \cos (e^t) + e^{-t} (-\sin(e^t)) e^t \big) \hat{i} + \big(- e^{-t} \sin(e^t) + e^{-t} \cos(e^t) e^t \big) \hat{j} - e^t \hat{k} \\ &= e^{-t} (- \cos(e^t) - \sin(e^t) e^t) \hat{i} + e^{-t} (-\sin(e^t) + \cos(e^t) e^t) \hat{j} - e^t \hat{k} \end{align*}

However, the answer at the back of my calculus textbook says it should be:

\begin{align*} \frac{d \hat{r}}{dt} = -(e^{-t} \cos(e^t) + \sin(e^t)) \hat{i} + (-e^{-t} \sin(e^t) + \cos(e^t) ) \hat{j} - e^t \hat{k} \end{align*}

So what did I do wrong? I just used the product rule and the chain rule for $\sin(e^t)$ and $\cos(e^t)$ ?

Comment: Your process is okay, you just screwed up with some signs and/or distributing. Try to do it again from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is correct, you just need to simplify a little more, using the fact that $e^{-t} \cdot e^t = 1$.